# Вывод options циклом в select с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть массив optionValues такого вида
["", "oil", "bitumen", "avs", "CMM"]
Это опции из select.
Как мне сделать так чтоб эти опции вывести в другом созданном select
В этой строке

```
document.getElementById("cat_val"+id).innerHTML="<select class='sel-cat'id='cat_val"+id+"' name='cat-select'></select>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var id = 10;
var array = ["oil", "bitumen", "avs", "CMM"];
var html = '<select class="sel-cat" id="cat_val'+id+'" name="cat-select">'

array.forEach(function(value){
  html += '<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>'; 
});

html += '</select>';

document.getElementById("cat_val"+id).innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="cat_val10"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает